# Shuffle character effect in backbone calling render multiple times

Tags: python, backbone.js

I've got a block of characters rendering in a template in Backbone. The template is receiving a list of characters and shuffling them (using underscore's shuffle method) then, displaying them on the screen in a grid. I thought it would be cool to render the screen several times and randomize the list each time so it has kind of a shuffle effect.

So I tried to do this in the view calling the template like this:

```
for(var i=1; i<50; i++){
     this.$el.html(this.template(jQuery.extend(this.model.toJSON(), extended_options)));..
}
```

And in the template:

```
 temp_list = _(listcontents).shuffle()
  for(var character in temp_list)
  { %> <span><%= temp_list[character] %></span> <% }
}
```

But I didn't see the shuffle effect at all. It just took a few seconds before the screen rendered one time.

How can I get this to repeat the render quickly in front of the users eyes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is rendering the template 50 times very quickly. You could do this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(...);
  }, i * 50);
```

What this is basically doing is spacing out the rendering at approx 50ms. You might have to tinker with the i * 50 portion to get the desired effect.